# WordPress TinyMCE get Content using POST

Tags: wordpress

I want to integrate tinymce editor into plugin options page and save its value.  I used
  wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() );  function to load the editor. But the content is not available in $_POST when its submitted

Any possible reasons ?

Answer (score 2):

test it: tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent();

;-)
PSO

Comment: Clarification: 'content_id' corresponds to $editor_id (2nd parameter of wp_editor function).